# Vertical centering of text in div not working

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have turned to [this guide](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/) to solve my problem of vertically centering my text within the div. And I believe to understand what it says, but it still doesn't work.

```
.number {
    position: relative;
    height:50px;
    margin: -25px 0 0 0;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5A9HP/3/), which recreates the problem. I want the green area (.number) to be centered vertically within the button (.numberElement)

Where is my problem? I reckon jQuery Mobile is complicating things and creating structures I am not foreseeing...

Thank you!

Sandro

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes to your css like so:

```
.numberElement {
    position: absolute;
    width:30%;
    height:200px;
    margin:0px;
    display:table;
}

.numberElement .ui-btn-inner {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5A9HP/4/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your top property of .number is not working fine, as i can see in your fiddle. Try changing it from top to margin-top. It will center around margin-top:60px;

Also dont forget to remove the line in .number

```
margin: -25px 0 0 0;
```

Comment: Hey guys! Thank you for the answers... Your answer, Freeman, got the centering about right. The others in my opinion didn't.

The thing is though, and I didn't explicitly mention that unfortunately, I want it to be centered irrespective of the height of the .numberElement

Comment: Sorry for delay, i just saw your comment. Set your margin-top to a percent unit. margin-top:50%; could work. PS: For some reason i cant open your fiddle anymore

Comment: It's still there. Just checked :-)

That was the idea of the article I went with was. Set top to 50%, then it should have the upper edge bang at the vertical middle, right? And then make a negative margin of half the height of the .number element to push it upwards enough... The author even suggested that I might use a percentage value for that later assignment. This is my current solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5A9HP/6/, which is still not like in the article really. Works so far though

Taking away the data-role="button" attribute from the div definitely was a help

Sandro

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct answer as i think

```
.numberElement {
    position: absolute;
    width:30%;
    height:200px;
    margin:0px;
}

.number {
    position: relative;
    height:50px;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height:50px;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #00ff00;
}

#grid {
    position:absolute;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:solid 1px #ff0000;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: This centers the 1 within the .number element, but unfortunately doesn't center .number within .numberElement at all. What I posted above still seems to be the best solution so far

Comment: hi, cant you just use jquery height()? and use it to calculate the place of central piece? i think it is just simpler?

Comment: Hey Homam! That would most likely work, but isn't CSS exactly there to avoid this? Can't believe it's so tricky to do this...

Comment: hi somethings in css is more trickier than it seems and these are mostly go around height and vertical alignment. another one like this is vertically equal hights that has an answer but this one in css has an answer that worked before but in most modern browser like chrome it wont work. you could make its display:table-cell and vertical-align: middle but its very risky specially in mobile browsers

Comment: I see, we are just not where we want to be in terms of cross-browser-compatibility, yet :-)

It's actually supposed to be part of a mobile app, so the mobile browser support is kind of relevant there